# Why bash special parameter * and @ starting from one?

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing

In `bash` man page, [Special Parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) says that:

> ($*) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.
>   ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.

Is this related to another special parameter `$0`?

```sh
❯ cat test_special.sh
#!/bin/bash
arr=( "$@" )
echo First parameter: $1
echo First element of @ : ${arr[0]}

echo "arr:1:2: ${arr[@]:1:2}"
echo "@:1:2: ${@:1:2}"
❯ bash ./test_special.sh a b c
First parameter: a
First element of @ : a
arr:1:2: b c
@:1:2: a b
```

The `${arr[@]:1:2}` acts different from `${@:1:2}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to mix up array indexing and parameter positions. In bash, arrays are indexed starting with 0. This applies to all arrays, including the special array `@`. Parameters are counted from 1, the special parameter 0 denoting the program which is invoked. This $0 is **not** stored inside `@`.

Hence the index 0 of `@` contains $1. You can easily test it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=( "$@" )
echo First parameter: $1
echo First element of @ : ${arr[0]}
```

Calling this script with a bunch of parameters, will show the same value in both *echo* statements.

**UPDATE** (triggered by the comment of the OP):

@LingSamuel has a point with his comment! It is even more obvious, if we output `${@:0:2}`, which clearly shows that `$0` (the script name) is contained in the result.

If we read the man bash manpage about `@` (in the section *Special Parameters*), we see that it does not mention `$0` anywhere (which is a shame), but only talks about the *positional parameters* (i.e. `$1` onwards).

But the man-page also does **not** claim, that `@` is an array, and indeed, I don't think it is one (at least not in the sense bash defines arrays). If `@` and `*` were arrays, we could do, i.e., a `${@[1]}`, because this is the way arrays are indexed (`${NAME[INDEX]}`), but with `@` this is not valid: If we try it, we get a *bad substitution* error.

The fact that we can *do* something like `${@:1:2}` (which BTW would be, if `@` were an array, a **substring** selection, not a **subscript** selection, as you can see with

```
arr=(ab cd ef)
echo ${arr:1:1} # Substring selection: Outputs just b
echo ${arr[@]:1:2}  # Subscript selection: Outputs cd
```

makes me conclude that all of the subscripting experiments we do on `@` and `*` is, from the viewpoint of the bash-man-page, an undocumented feature, perhaps (my personal guess) implemented to maintain compatibility with Bourne shell (which did not have arrays in the bash sense).

As soon as we don't regard `@` as an array anymore, but, as the man page says, as **special** parameter, with its own special rules, we don't have to be surprised that it performs in the way you expected.

Comment: In fact this question comes from such case: `${arr[@]:1:2}` acts different from `${@:1:2}`.
Script added in question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this related to another special parameter `$0`?

Yes. That's the name of the script, just like how in C programs `argv[0]` is the name of the program that was executed. Then `$1` is the first argument, `$2` the second argument, and so on.

Comment: So there is a trick when we use `$@` and `$*`? It doesn't print `$0`.

Comment: @LingSamuel: if you want $0 too, the trick is easy: just write "$0 $*" instead of simply "$*"...

Comment: I am not asking how to access `$0`. My question is *why* `$@` and `$*` starting from 1. The real array `$@` and `$*` contains `$0` or not, if not, why they still starting from 1.

Comment: @LingSamuel They're not arrays.

Comment: (Though if you use substring evaluation with `@`, offset 0 is the value of `$0`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html for examples)